# Pebble SDK/SimplyJS not honoring the \t character

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm having an interesting time trying to get my Pebble watch to honor the escape sequence character `\t` when pushing data to my watch (using SimplyJS).

The following snippet is the code that I have been using:

```
simply.scrollable(true);
simply.style('small');
simply.fullscreen(true);

var aflLadderUrl = 'http://www.sportal.com.au/feeds/sss/afl_ladder.json';

var ladderContent = '';

ajax({ url: aflLadderUrl, type: 'json'}, 
  function(data) {
   var i = 0;
   while (i < 18){
     ladderContent = ladderContent + data.ladder[i].friendly_name + '\t\t\t' + data.ladder[i].percentage + '\n';
        i++;  
   } 
   simply.text({
     title: 'AFL Ladder',
     body: ladderContent
   });
  }, 
  function() {
   simply.text({
    title: 'AFL Ladder',
    body: 'No internet connection'
   });
  }
);
```

What I am currently observing is that the `\n` is being honored and I can see that on my watch, each row of data is being displayed on a separate line. However, it appears that my `\t` are being ignored and instead of a tab being inserted into my line, zero whitespace is being displayed (i.e. `'my name is' + '\t\t\t' + 'dave'` is displayed as `my name isdave`).

I have also tried compiling a Hello World program using just the Pebble SDK (taking the code from https://github.com/kristofvc/pebble-hello-world/blob/master/src/pebble_hello_world.c and adding a couple of `\t\t` in the string to be printed on line 11) and have also noticed that the SDK honors `\n` characters but not `\t` characters (just as my SimplyJS app did).

My question is: is it possible to have the Pebble (either via the SDK or SimplyJS) display tabs the same way you'd expect them to work when printing to console? I understand the \t character may not be supported and instead of using `\t` I could just use spaces, but this one had me curious.

Please let me know if you require any more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\t` is a control (non-printable) character, it doesn't correspond to any glyph and won't get "displayed" consistently, if at all. Terminal emulators will interpret it differently than spreadsheet software reading a TSV file, for example. It sounds like the part of the Pebble's firmware that converts a bytestring to pixels on a display just ignores `\t`, although I couldn't find this in the SDK documentation.

If you're using a fixed-width font, you can implement your own tabs using spaces, like this:

```
var data = {ladder: [
  {friendly_name: "Cool Team", percentage: 80.0},
  {friendly_name: "Really Cool Team", percentage: 80.0},
  {friendly_name: "The Coolest Team of All", percentage: 80.0}
]}

var len = function(obj) {return obj.friendly_name.length}
var longer = function(a, b) {return len(a) > len(b) ? a : b}
var longestName = len(data.ladder.reduce(longer))

var tab = function(obj) { return new Array(longestName - len(obj) + 2).join(" ") }
var print = function(obj) { return obj.friendly_name + tab(obj) + obj.percentage }

var ladderContent = data.ladder.map(print).join("\n")
// Cool Team               80
// Really Cool Team        80
// The Coolest Team of All 80
```

Comment: Thanks man - this is the best explanation I've received in regards to this. It seems interesting that some fonts apparently don't seem to display newlines either but your answer seems pretty solid.